# Initiating a redirect from and admin role to a client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket

Working on an app that I would like to have that when an admin pushes "start chat" it redirects them to an off server chat session. Is this possible using something like websockets? I'm a fairly new rails developer and have found https://github.com/ngauthier/tubesock but really have no idea how to go about doing that...

My knowledge is limited to pretty much rails, some JS, reasonable html/css etc. I have found an example app that shows tubesock working to publish simple string inputs in real time, but that is it.

Are there any good guides etc that would show me what is going on with websockets to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using node.js and express.js.  Using node you can push from the server to a specific client, and then have a simple window.location and a passed in param to get it to redirect.  This is my favorite example of these technologies.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socketio-and-expressjs--net-31708

Comment: Being relatively bad at JS/newbish programmer do you see this as being a problem for me using node.js? I just skimmed through that, and it doesn't look overly complex, but looking and implementing I have found can be two different things =). It does look like a very thought out guide though, which I haven't found for anything involving websockets. Thanks for the response!